# logistic regression with independent categorical variables with more than two possible values using stata

Tags: logistic

I have to do a logistic regression with independent categorical variables with more than two possible values. Which is the best way to deal with such variables using Stata or spss? I need to have Odds ratios in the output. Thanks.

Comment: I have removed your signature. There's no need to sign your posts as your name appears immediately underneath anyway. Please see [this section of the faq](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)

Answer (score 1):

For IVs? Dummy variables. But stats packages should be able to set those up for you automatically.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_%28statistics%29